# Wikis features when having an Enterprise wiki Vs having a wiki page library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am reading about wiki in SP2013, and some tutorials talks about Wiki pages when creating either:-

1. Publishing site ------> enterprise wiki
2. Team site-----> wiki pages OR wiki page libraries.

But I cannot figure out what are the major differences between the two wiki pages from the following perspectives:-

1. End-user perspective, mainly the capabilities within the wiki pages
2. Administrator perspectives.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alerts and content types are not working / possible by default in a wiki library. (there is a workaround to enable content types using Powershell)

On top of the page layouts an Enterprise wiki has page ratings, categories and reusable content.

On a personal note I feel that enterprise wiki is a little more collaborative while a wiki library is more a one way communication channel.